# Summed area table (integral image) returns nonsenses on rectangle sum

Tags: java, image-processing, computer-vision

So here on wikipedia you can see an article describing [how summed area table (integral image) works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table). It's a very important part of computer vision and image analysis.

I'm trying to implement it. The concept is really simple:

1. Make an `array[imageheight][imagewidth]`
2. Every array member should contain sum of all pixels before and above in the original image
3. To get sum on any rectangle, use `A-B-C+D` formula, where ABCD is this rectangle:
   [image: summed area table sum - wikipedia]

So I made this function to sum all pixels on `BufferedImage`:

```
  public static double[][] integralImageGrayscale(BufferedImage image) {
    //Cache width and height in variables
    int w = image.getWidth();
    int h = image.getHeight();
    //Create the 2D array as large as the image is
    //Notice that I use [Y, X] coordinates to comply with the formula
    double integral_image[][] = new double[h][w];
    //Sum to be assigned to the pixels
    double the_sum = 0;
    //Well... the loop
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
      for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        //Get pixel. It's actually 0xAARRGGBB, so the function should be getARGB
        int pixel = image.getRGB(x, y);
        //Extrapolate color values from the integer 
        the_sum+= ((pixel&0x00FF0000)>>16)+((pixel&0x0000FF00)>>8)+(pixel&0x000000FF);
        integral_image[y][x] = the_sum;
      }
    }
    //Return the array
    return integral_image;
  }
```

I also made a debug function and it's convincing me that it works:

[image: normal and integral image]
<sup>Notice how the white areas influence the sum of the image</sup>

But if I make this test case:

```
   //Summed area table (thing is BufferedImage)
   double is[][] = ScreenWatcher.integralImageGrayscale(thing);
   //Sum generated by a normal for loop
   double ss = ScreenWatcher.grayscaleSum(thing);
   //Height of the resulting array
   int ish = is.length;
   //Width of resulting array. Also throws nasty error if something goes wrong
   int isw = is[is.length-1].length;
   //Testing whether different methods give same results
   System.out.println(
       ss +" =? " + 
     //Last "pixel" in integral image must contain the sum of the image
       is[ish-1][isw-1]+" =? "+
     //The "sum over rectangle" with a rectangle that contains whole image
     //     A            B            C              D
       (+is[0][0]  -is[0][isw-1] -is[ish-1][0] +is[ish-1][isw-1])
   );
```

I get a sad result:

```
1.7471835E7 =? 1.7471835E7 =? 112455.0
```

Interesting thing is, that pure white image returns 0:

```
7650000.0 =? 7650000.0 =? 0.0  - this was 100x100 white image and 765 is 3*255 so everything seems right
```

I have no idea how to get to the bottom of this. Everything seems too clear to contain a mistake. So either there's a typo in the code above, or the logic is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: If you are trying to calculate the grayscale value of the pixel, the component values should be unevenly weighted, since otherwise the blue component has too much influence. One commonly-used weighting is $0.33R + 0.59G + 0.11B$; others can be found via a search engine of choice.

Comment: I'm doing this for computer vision. Computer doesn't really care that our human eyes are broken and see different intensity in every color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
//Extrapolate color values from the integer 
the_sum+= ((pixel&0x00FF0000)>>16)+((pixel&0x0000FF00)>>8)+(pixel&0x000000FF);
integral_image[y][x] = the_sum;
```

What you should be doing is:

```
int A = (x > 0 && y > 0) ? integral_image[y-1][x-1] : 0;
int B = (x > 0) ? integral_image[y][x-1] : 0;
int C = (y > 0) ? integral_image[y-1][x] : 0;
integral_image[y][x] = - A + B + C
    + ((pixel&0x00FF0000)>>16)+((pixel&0x0000FF00)>>8)+(pixel&0x000000FF);
```

(with no `the_sum` variable).

---

Evaluating the sum for the portion of the image `(minx, miny) -> (maxx, maxy)` inclusively can now be done in constant time using the values in `integral_image`:

```
double A = (minx > 0 && miny > 0) ? integral_image[miny-1][minx-1] : 0;
double B = (minx > 0) ? integral_image[maxy][minx-1] : 0;
double C = (miny > 0) ? integral_image[miny-1][maxx] : 0;
double D = integral_image[maxy][maxx];

double sum = A - B - C + D;
```

Note that `minx-1` and `miny-1` are used because of the inclusivity on the minimum coordinates.

Comment: Seems I misunderstood the whole concept. I think now it's right. I get `7650000.0 =? 7650000.0 =? 7497765.0` for the 100x100 white image. I guess the last number is smaller because the search range excludes the left and top borders. Can this be overcome?

Comment: This method gives you the sum of the image in the range `min_x < x <= max_x` and `min_y < y <= max_y` (note the `<` and `<=` carefully). If you want to sum inclusively on the min coordinates, just decrease `min_x` and `min_y` by 1.

Comment: But what if `min_x = 0`?

Comment: Just define that the value of that pixel is 0.

Comment: I'm sorry for repetitive questions, but how should I do that? Your answer is valid and correct the way it is already, but if you could explain this additionally in your answer, it might help other people as well as me. Thank you for helping! :)

Comment: I think, the last code block has a mistake(Copy&Paste?) `double B = (minx > 0) ? integral_image[maxy][miny-1] : 0;`  should be `double B = (minx > 0) ? integral_image[maxy][minx-1] : 0;` (the last miny->minx).

Comment: @FrankM I cannot remember anything about this question, but looks like you are right. Edited, thanks.